# Rails4: How to apply Bootstrap to simple_nested_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to apply bootstrap to the input fields as following.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Title</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

My current code is as following.

_form.html.erb

```
  <%= simple_nested_form_for @event do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { rows: 5, cols: 30 } %>
    <%= f.input :charge_person %>
    .
    .
    .
  <% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me the best way in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Title</span>
    <%= f.input :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
    <%= f.input :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Charge Person</span>
    <%= f.input :charge_person, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Andrew Hendrie. It works after adding `label: false` like `<%= f.input :title, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldl read more detail [SIMPLE FORM DOCS](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @event, , wrapper_html: { class: 'input-group' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, wrapper_html: { class: 'input-group-addon' } %>
  <%= f.input_field :title, wrapper_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  .
  .
  .
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Oleg Sobchuk. Although it doesn't work, SIMPLE FORM DOCS is helpful for me. Thank you.